# how could i disable auto search for Three20 search bar

Tags: ios, three20

I am using Three20 framework, and the auto search feature make the searching really slow, i'd like to disable the auto search and fire the searching once the user clicks on the "Search" button on the pad.

Is there any way i can disable the auto search? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new display controller `XXSearchDisplayController` derived from `TTSearchDisplayController`, in the `XXSearchDisplayController.m`

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller    
 shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
return NO;
}
```

This will disable the auto searching. After this, go to your class derived from `TTTableViewController`, say `XXProductsTableViewController`

```
@implementation XXProductsTableViewController
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        UISearchBar* searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
        searchBar.delegate = self;
        _searchController = [[XXSearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragama mark - UISearchBarDelegate
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [self.searchViewController.dataSource search:searchBar.text];
}
@end
```

The above code will do the searching once the user clicks on the "Search" button